# remove extended attribute : fails

Tags: file, shell, scripting, file-attributes, xattr

From a shell script, I'm trying to remove extended attribute

> setfattr -x security.selinux file.txt

The file.txt has mode 777, but im getting "permission denied error".

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the user will need to run your script using `sudo`.